# Unable to use POI HSSF library in Eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse-plugin, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, poi-hssf

I am developing an Eclipse plugin to create and perform operations on excel files and I am not able to use the POI HSSF library for the same. 
I have downloaded the *poi-3.7-20101029.jar* file. When I tried using this in an independent java application by adding it in the configure build path, the thing worked. But when I tried using the same during developing the plugin in the Eclipse PDE, I get a *NoClassDefFound* exception for the HSSFWorkbook class. I have added the POI plugin in the build path (and confirmed that the plugin contains the HSSFWorkbook class) as well as imported the HSSFWorkbook class.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Is there something else I need to add or modify while using the POI library in plugin development? Should I add the library as dependencies in the Manifest file?

Thanks and Regards...

Swaraj

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the library to the plugin classpath. To do this, open your MANIFEST.MF and select the tab "Runtime". Then, in the "Classpath" section, click on the "Add" button. A dialog will open up, select your jar from there.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Glad to hear it! BTW, accepting the answer is really the nicest way one can say 'thank you' here on SO ;-).